# Perform several ANOVA's simultaneously on tidy data in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, anova, simultaneous

I have a dataframe that looks like the following but with many additional rows. "Content" and "Process" can both either be "a" or "n".

```
dv1  dv2  dv3  content  process
1    3    4    a        a
2    1    2    a        n
5    3    5    n        a
4    3    2    n        n
```

I know how to run several ANOVA's on data that is set up this way. I would run the following:

```
dv <- df[,1:3]
output <- lm(as.matrix(dv) ~ content * proces, data = df, 
    contrasts = list(content = contr.sum, process = contr.sum))
summary(aov(output))
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do the same thing on a tidy dataframe without just putting it back into the same format it's in above using spread(). I typically work with tidy data, and ANOVA's are one of the only analyses I still run on un-tidy data. Alternatively, if you think it's really better to run ANOVA's the way I've been doing it and that I'm creating more work for myself by trying to do everything within the tidyverse, please let me know.

This is what the tidy dataframe would look like:

```
dv   value  content  process 
dv1  1      a        a
dv1  2      a        n
dv1  5      n        a
dv1  4      n        n
dv2  3      a        a
dv2  1      a        n
dv2  3      n        a
dv2  3      n        n
dv3  4      a        a
dv3  2      a        n
dv3  5      n        a
dv3  2      n        n
```

Answer (score 3):

The "tidy" way would be to `nest` data by `dv` and then use `purrr::map` to perform ANOVAs on the nested data.

```
library(tidyverse)
df.aov <- df %>%
    group_by(dv) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(aov = map(data, ~aov(value ~ content * process, data = .x)))
df.aov$aov
#[[1]]
#Call:
#   aov(formula = value ~ content * process, data = .x)
#
#Terms:
#                content process content:process
#Sum of Squares        9       0               1
#Deg. of Freedom       1       1               1
#
#Estimated effects may be unbalanced
#
#[[2]]
#Call:
#   aov(formula = value ~ content * process, data = .x)
#
#Terms:
#                content process content:process
#Sum of Squares        1       1               1
#Deg. of Freedom       1       1               1
#
#Estimated effects may be unbalanced
#
#[[3]]
#Call:
#aov(formula = value ~ content * process, data = .x)
#
#Terms:
#                    content process content:process
#Sum of Squares     0.25    6.25            0.25
#Deg. of Freedom       1       1               1
#
#Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

`df.aov` contains two columns `data` and `aov` that contain a `list` of `tibble`s and `aov`s, respectively.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "dv   value  content  process
dv1  1      a        a
dv1  2      a        n
dv1  5      n        a
dv1  4      n        n
dv2  3      a        a
dv2  1      a        n
dv2  3      n        a
dv2  3      n        n
dv3  4      a        a
dv3  2      a        n
dv3  5      n        a
dv3  2      n        n", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a follow up question: how do we input parameters of anova when using the map function?
variations of `mutate(aov = map(data, ~anova(type = 2)))`  does not work, however the following works: `mutate(aov = map(data, anova))`

Comment: @coreehi You can do `mutate(aov = map(data, anova, type = 2)` or `mutate(aov = map(data, ~anova(.x, type = 2))` or `mutate(aov = map(data, function(x) anova(x, type = 2))`. The function argument of `map` takes either a function name or an anonymous (lambda-style) function (the latter either as a formula or as an explicit anon function).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use tidyr's `gather()` to reshape wide and run your same process:

```
sdf <- tidyr::spread(tidy_data, dv, value)
sdf
#   content process dv1 dv2 dv3
# 1       a       a   1   3   4
# 2       a       n   2   1   2
# 3       n       a   5   3   5
# 4       n       n   4   3   2

dv <- sdf[,3:5]
output <- lm(as.matrix(dv) ~ content * process, data = sdf, 
             contrasts = list(content = contr.sum, process = contr.sum))
summary(aov(output))
```

Data

```
txt <- "dv   value  content  process 
dv1  1      a        a
dv1  2      a        n
dv1  5      n        a
dv1  4      n        n
dv2  3      a        a
dv2  1      a        n
dv2  3      n        a
dv2  3      n        n
dv3  4      a        a
dv3  2      a        n
dv3  5      n        a
dv3  2      n        n"

tidy_data <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using spread() and while still staying in the tidy format? Or is the best way to do this to work in the un-tidy format?